# How to declare nested functions in a TypeScript declaration source file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm in the process of building a declaration source file for [KeyboardJS](http://robertwhurst.github.com/KeyboardJS/).  The API is referenced from a static object (KeyboardJS) instantiated when the JavaScript file is loaded.  A few of the methods of the API are nested under other methods.  For example:

```
KeyboardJS.clear(keyCombo);
```

and

```
KeyboardJS.clear.key(key);
```

Here is my interface definition:

```
interface KeyboardJSStatic {
    enable(): void;
    disable(): void;
    activeKeys(): string[];
    on(keyCombo:string, onDownCallback?: (keyEvent: Event, keysPressed: string[], keyCombo: string) => {}, onUpCallback?: (keyEvent: Event, keysPressed: string[], keyCombo: string) => {}): KeyboardJSBinding;
    clear(keyCombo: string): void;
    clear.key(keyName: string): void;
    locale(localeName: string): KeyboardJSLocale;
    locale.register(localeName: string, localeDefinition: KeyboardJSLocale): void;
    macro(keyCombo:string , keyNames: string[]): void;
    macro.remove(keyCombo: string): void;
    key: KeyboardJSKey;
    combo: KeyboardJSCombo; 
}
```

The TypeScript plugin for Visual Studio 2012 is generating and error on the clear.key line, recommending a semicolon for where the period is.  Has anyone built a definition file with a similar scenario?  Thanks!

Comment: Once done, you are more than welcome to submit the definition file to https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: Thanks Boris. Honestly, that was my plan all along.  Great job with DefinitelyTyped!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can declare call signatures on types like this:

```
interface KeyboardJSStatic {
    // ...
    clear: {
        (keyCombo: string): void; // Call signature
        key(keyName: string): void; // Method
    };
    // ...
}

var n: KeyboardJSStatic;
n.clear('a'); // OK
n.clear.key('b'); // OK
```

Comment: Exactly. Also you can declare the whole thing as a ' interface KeyboardJsClear { }'

Answer (score 2):

Genius comment from Ryan. Using the same pattern as the jQuery definition you could do:

```
interface KeyboardJSClear {
    (keyCombo: string) : void;
    key(keyName: string): void;
}

interface KeyboardJSLocale {
    (localeName: string) : KeyboardJSLocale;
    register(localeName: string, localeDefinition: KeyboardJSLocale): void;
}

interface KeyboardJSMacro {
    (keyCombo:string , keyNames: string[]): void;
    remove(keyCombo: string): void;
}

interface KeyboardJSStatic {
    enable(): void;
    disable(): void;
    activeKeys(): string[];
    on(keyCombo:string, onDownCallback?: (keyEvent: Event, keysPressed: string[], keyCombo: string) => {}, onUpCallback?: (keyEvent: Event, keysPressed: string[], keyCombo: string) => {}): KeyboardJSBinding;
    clear: KeyboardJSClear;
    locale: KeyboardJSLocale;
    macro: KeyboardJSMacro;
    key: KeyboardJSKey;
    combo: KeyboardJSCombo; 
}

declare var KeyboardJS: KeyboardJSStatic;

KeyboardJS.clear('');
KeyboardJS.clear.key('');
```

Comment: Think about the jquery definitions. `$()` and `$.ajax()` etc

Comment: Thanks guys, this was a big help.